# What's the best way to install solana wallet adapter?

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter, installation

[image: This is the error that appears when you run the NPM code for wallet adapter]

From the solana cookbook (https://solanacookbook.com/getting-started/installation.html#install-web3-js), one is able to install  web3.js and Spl token libraries via NPM, but can't do so for wallet adapter.

Answer (score 3):

See the guide for apps here: https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/blob/master/APP.md

At minimum, you'll want `@solana/wallet-adapter-base` and usually `@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets`, but you'll also likely want `@solana/wallet-adapter-react` or one of the community-maintained UI framework libraries.

See https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/blob/master/PACKAGES.md for all Wallet Adapter packages.

Answer (score 2):

Try

> npm i @solana/wallet-adapter-wallets

or if doesn't work out you clone directly from [GitHub](https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this simple & easy-to-follow guide to follow the latest steps for integrating the wallet adapter in your dapp.

https://www.solanawalletadapter.xyz/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey @saumay this is both a duplicate answer and a single link to a guide. I'd recommend putting the actual answer here and then back linking as a resource